Insert a row in pandas dataframe
I have below pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,5], 'B': [7,6,7,8]})

Now I have a list
List = [99, 88]

I want to insert this list at the row number 2.
Is there any method available to achieve this? I found there is a method called insert, however this only insert column at designated place.

You could use iloc and concat:
N = 2

List = [99, 88]

out = pd.concat([dat.iloc[:N],
                 pd.DataFrame([List], columns=dat.columns),
                 dat.iloc[N:]], ignore_index=True)

Alternatively, if you have a (sorted) range index, you could insert with an index just before the desired position (e.g. 1.5) and sort_index:
N = 2
dat.loc[N-0.5] = List
dat.sort_index(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

Output:
    A   B
0   1   7
1   2   6
2  99  88
3   3   7
4   5   8

If you want to replace the existing data, just assign:
dat.loc[2] = List

Output:
    A   B
0   1   7
1   2   6
2  99  88
3   5   8

To perform this in a pipe you should probably use a custom function:
def assign_chain(df, pos, obj):
    df = df.copy()
    df.loc[pos] = obj
    return df

out = (pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,5], 'B' : [7,6,7,8]})
         .pipe(assign_chain, 2, List)
      )


Thanks. However, when insertion at specific row happen, the existing values of that row should be deleted, so that new dat would have same number of rows. Is there any way to modify this?

@Bogaso then just dat.loc[2] = List?

Thats perfect. Is it possible to implement this using chain rule i.e. using pipe (or similar) method?

@Bogaso then you need a custom function to make a copy, see update
